# Is it possible to deploy an express api and socket.io server in the same server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm building an api for an api but want socket.io as well listening on different port, I served it on my local machine and it seems to work fine.As soon as I deploy it it does not work.

Server:

```
// Import stuff...

const app: express.Express = express();
const httpServer: any = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer);

const PORT: number = Number(process.env.PORT) || 3000;
const SOCKET_PORT: number = Number(process.env.SOCKET_PORT) || 3001;

dotenv.config();
debug.init();

mongoose.connect(String(process.env.DATABASE_URI));

// Endpoints...

// Socket server:

io.on("connection", (socket: Socket): void => {
  socket.on(
    "server-message",
    async (
      payload: MessageSchemaType,
      key: string,
      responseToken: string
    ): Promise<void> => {
      if (key === process.env.KEY) {
        io.emit(`client-message:room(${payload.room})`, payload);

       }
  );
});

app.listen(PORT, (): void => {
  debug.log(
    `Server Ready and listening on port ${PORT}, press CTRL + C to stop operation.`
  );
});

httpServer.listen(SOCKET_PORT, (): void => {
  debug.log(`Socket listening on port ${SOCKET_PORT}`);
});
```

Client:

```
// Import stuff...

// This is not working:
const socket = io("https://myapp.herokuapp.com:3001/")
```

It seems that the client is not connecting to the server and it's giving me a error saying "connection refused"

Comment: Yes, you can without any problem having a node application that serve ExpressAPI an Socket.io in the same tiome

Comment: Shouldn't `io()` take a `wss://` url, rather than `https`?

Comment: But how do I call the socket(which is on a different port as shown)?